# How to set position from StreamReader file

Tags: c#, console-application

Okay here's the thing. I tired to try make position from `StreamReader` file. I also already try using `Console.SetCursorPosition` with function but it only change on first row in file text. My question is, how to make position for all rows in file. Here's my file:

```
 N01    Chicken Nugget  20000   0
 N02    Tempe Nugget    15000   0
 N03    Tofu Nugget     15000   0
```

and here's the output, which is not display N word causing hide on left frame.[Click to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5THH.png) and [my expectation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogj8j.png)

Here's my code

```
namespace Nugget
{
    class case1
    {
        public void cs1()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗");
            Console.WriteLine("║ProID\tProduct Name\tPrice\tStock\t\t\t\t\t\t\t║");
            Console.WriteLine("╠═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣");
            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(@"E:\CCIT\Semester 2\Q1\Project 1\AbsolutlyRealGetNugget\Nugget.txt");
            string sLine = "";
            ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();
            while (sLine != null)
            {
                sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
                if (sLine != null)
                    arrText.Add(sLine);
            }
            objReader.Close();
            foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
            Console.WriteLine(sOutput);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 4);
            Console.WriteLine("║");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 5);
            Console.WriteLine("║");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 6);
            Console.WriteLine("║");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(88, 4);
            Console.WriteLine("║");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(88, 5);
            Console.WriteLine("║");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(88, 6);
            Console.WriteLine("║");
            Console.WriteLine("╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Maybe it's just me, but I really don't understand what you are asking for. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What did you expect and what happened instead? And please show the code you tried and that caused the problem. You may have a look at [ask], and try to provide a [mcve]. I edited your question so that the screen shot is directly visible for readers who might help you, but for some reason you removed that again.

Comment: Ohh thanks for remind, i noob here, another day when i ask question, i would describe more detail. i already add my source code and my expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also already try using Console.SetCursorPosition with function but
>   it only change on first row in file text.

Your current `foreach` loop code of:

```
foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
Console.WriteLine(sOutput);
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 4);
... more code ...
```

**does not** have any brackets `{` and `}`, which means only the line **directly** below the `foreach` line gets repeated.  To make the whole **block** get repeated for each iteration, insert brackets like this:

```
foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sOutput);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 4);
    ... more code ...
}
```

With that said, I would approach it this way instead:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string nugget = @"C:\Users\mikes\Documents\Nugget.txt";
        string[] arrText = File.ReadAllLines(nugget);

        int menuWidth = 89;
        string bar = new string('═', menuWidth - 2);

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("╔" + bar + "╗");
        Console.Write("║ProID\tProduct Name\tPrice\tStock");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(menuWidth - 1, Console.CursorTop);
        Console.WriteLine("║");
        Console.WriteLine("╠" + bar + "╣");

        foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
        {   
            Console.Write(sOutput);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
            Console.Write("║");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(menuWidth - 1, Console.CursorTop);
            Console.WriteLine("║");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("╚" + bar + "╝");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Note that I'm using both `Console.WriteLine()` and `Console.Write()`.  The latter method will output to the console **without** a line terminator, thus leaving the cursor on the **same** line.  Afterwards, we can move the cursor to the right edge of the menu, on the same line via `Console.CursorTop`, and draw the vertical bar with:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(menuWidth - 1, Console.CursorTop);
Console.WriteLine("║");
```

This produced the following output:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ProID  Product Name    Price   Stock                                                   ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║N01    Chicken Nugget  20000   0                                                       ║
║N02    Tempe Nugget    15000   0                                                       ║
║N03    Tofu Nugget     15000   0                                                       ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```